# Hue difference when using multiple and different GPUs together

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I tried to use my older GTX 560 Ti with my GTX 780 to get faster renders, but I encountered this strange behavior when combining them :

[image: GTX 780 + GTX 560 Ti]

I thought that the different CUDA kernels (sm_35 and sm_21) were the cause of this weird tiling effect.
However, this does not happen when I use only one GPU (and I get exactly the same results for both GPUs, no blue hue) :

GTX 560 Ti only :
[image: GTX 560 Ti]

GTX 780 only :

[image]

If you have any idea that may explain this, please let me know! :)

Comment: As I can't add the links in the original post, here you go ;) :

GTX 780 : http://i.imgur.com/ugGdCfk.jpg
GTX 560 Ti : https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2k82.jpg

Comment: I think that the most likely explanation is that you found a bug. [Best place to put bug reports?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: I'm going to make further experimentation on this issue and I'll submit a bug report then ;)

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: I compile my own version from Git : 

version: 2.78 (sub 5), branch: master, commit date: 2017-07-17 16:31, hash: 9bbb197, build date: 17-Jul-17, 21:48

Comment: before you report anything please use a release version andcheck if you get different results.

Comment: That's what I was going to do, don't worry ;) I'm currently troubleshooting the issues, and it seems like it has to do with Image Texture color handling

Comment: Problem not occurring with the official 64-bits Blender version (2.78.1). May have something to do with the latest commits...

Comment: Make sure **this is not an issue of your particular build**. If it is also present in master then do submit a bug report.

Comment: I also tested on a build from GraphicAll.org and I found the same bug.

Comment: Just to let you know, it has been fixed recently, following the bug report ;)